# How to keep the only characters I want

Tags: python

I need to keep a certain character for my python project which and I don’t want to replace every unused character with ‘’ is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to enhance your question. You can [edit] your question with details at any time. As it stands, your question lacks information vital to being answered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function re.sub in re library

For example:

```
 data = re.sub('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNNM+/-', '', data)
```

This will keep every character in the first parameter replace with the second parameter by using String from the third parameter

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep "d" in the string

```py
origin = "abcdefghidx"
result = "".join([c for c in origin if c=="d"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.replace('what to want to delete', 'what you want to add').
ex-

```
name = "stackoverflow"
newName = name.replace('o', '0')
```

newName becomes 'stack0verfl0w'